# No type parameters for method with tricky Higher Kind

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

Let's set up issue conditions

```scala
trait Bound

class T1[B <: Bound]

class WrapperT1[B <: Bound, T2[B2 <: Bound] <: T1[B2]](val t: T2[B])

class WrapperT2[HB <: Bound, B <: HB, T2[B2 <: HB] <: T1[B2]](val t: T2[B])
```

Problem comes when i'm defining a method to auto infered argument type on `WrapperT2`.

```scala
def autoInferedMethod[B <: Bound, T2[B2 <: Bound] <: T1[B2]](arg: WrapperT1[B, T2]): Unit = Unit

def notAutoInferedMethod[HB <: Bound, B <: HB, T2[B2 <: HB] <: T1[B2]](arg: WrapperT2[HB, B, T2]): Unit = Unit

// Works
autoInferedMethod(new WrapperT1[Bound, T1](new T1[Bound]))
// Works
autoInferedMethod(new WrapperT1(new T1[Bound]))

// Doesn't works
notAutoInferedMethod(new WrapperT2[Bound, Bound, T1](new T1[Bound]))
// Compilator errors

no type parameters for method notAutoInferedMethod: (arg: ex.Q2.WrapperT2[HB,B,T2])Unit exist so that it can be applied to arguments (ex.Q2.WrapperT2[ex.Bound,ex.Bound,ex.T1])

[error]  --- because ---

[error] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;

[error]  found   : ex.Q2.WrapperT2[ex.Bound,ex.Bound,ex.T1]

[error]  required: ex.Q2.WrapperT2[?HB,?B,?T2]

[error]     notAutoInferedMethod(new WrapperT2[Bound, Bound, T1](new T1[Bound]))

[error]  found   : ex.Q2.WrapperT2[ex.Bound,ex.Bound,ex.T1]

[error]  required: ex.Q2.WrapperT2[HB,B,T2]

[error]     notAutoInferedMethod(new WrapperT2[Bound, Bound, T1](new T1[Bound]))
```

I'm supposed it comes from

```scala
[HB <: Bound, ..., T2[B2 <: HB] <: ...]
```

But i have no idea for why and if there it exists a workaround for it, any help to understand this issue is welcome.

### Update, it seems to works on 2.13 but not on 2.11/2.12

Comment: What is your Scala version? On ammonite with 2.13 it works.

Comment: Tried on 2.11.x, 2.12.x